# calculate distance by select checkbox and click button submit then go to next xml layout android

Tags: android

please someone help me find the solution..
how to calculate my distance?.. i have the distance values.. for example i have 4 places A,B,C and D.

```
distance(A,A,0);
distance(A,B,10.1);
distance(A,C,10.3);
distance(A,D,10.9);
distance(B,A,9.1);
distance(B,B,0);
distance(B,C,0.2);
distance(B,D,5.3);
distance(C,A,9.2);
distance(C,B,0.2);
distance(C,C,0);
distance(C,D,4.9);
distance(D,A,10.8);
distance(D,B,4.5);
distance(D,C,4);
distance(D,D,0);
```

this is my distance.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/A_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:text="@string/A"
    android:textSize="5pt" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/B_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:text="@string/B"
    android:textSize="5pt" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/C_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:text="@string/C"
    android:textSize="5pt" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/D_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:text="@string/D"
    android:textSize="5pt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:textSize="5pt" />
```

result.xml layout will do..
after select and submit.. the distance will calculate and show the selected place from the smallest distance and the total distance.

```
for example--> i select A,B,C and D..
the result will show --> B->C->D->A..
the total distance --> 15.9km..
```

so, this is my idea.. how many do i have to create activity.java?

Comment: Believe you're looking for a minimum spanning tree algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree can you confirm this will probably help others guide you since the general problem is already solved, then it's just a matter of if these have been implemented in Java classes you can easily access which I don't have an answer to.

Comment: shaunhusain seems to get it, but just fyi: Your question is kind of unclear.

Comment: code android for "checkbox with values and then submit button to calculate the selected checkbox values and the result show on another xml layout"..